# Download from source and upload to gcloud using cloud function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, axios

I'm using a service called opentok which store video on their cloud and give me a callback url when file are ready so that i can download it and store on my cloud provider.

We use gcloud where we work and i need to download the file, then store it on my gcloud bucket with a firebase cloud functions.

Here is my code :

```js
    const archiveFile = await axios.get(
      'https://sample-videos.com/video701/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb.mp4'
    );
    console.log('file downloaded from opentokCloud !');

    fs.writeFile('archive.mp4', archiveFile, err => {
      if (err) throw err;
      // success case, the file was saved
      console.log('File Saved in container');
    });

    await firebaseBucket.upload('archive.mp4', {
      gzip: true,
      // destination: `archivedStreams/${archiveInfo.id}/archive.mp4`,
      destination: 'test/lapin.mp4',
      metadata: {
        cacheControl: 'no-cache',
      },
    });
```

I tried to put directly the file downloaded in the `upload()` but it does not work i have to provide a String (path of my file)
How can i have the path of my downloaded file in the cloud function ? Is it still in the RAM of my container or in a cache folder ?

As you can see i tried to write with FS but i have no write access in the container of the cloud function

Thanks in advance to the community

Comment: Do not post source code as pictures. How large is the file (archive.mp4)? How much memory is assigned to the function? In general, Cloud Functions is the wrong service for copying files to cloud storage for anything large than a few MB. Everything in Cloud Functions is memory.

Comment: effectively, code updated with inline code.
On the example the video is 2MB but in the end it will be larger file

Comment: @JohnHanley what service would be best in Gcloud for that type of usage ?

Comment: "In the end it will be larger". Select your design for what you need in the end. Cloud Functions has both a runtime and memory limit. For your task, I use Compute Engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is looking for this in the futur here is how i solved it :

With Firebase cloud functions you can write temporary files in `/tmp` (see here for more information https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system)

I solved the problem by using `node-fetch` package and`writeStream` function of Node.JS :

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const fs = require('fs');

await fetch(archiveInfo.url).then(res => {
  console.log('start writing data');
  const dest = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/archive.mp4');
  res.body.pipe(dest);

  //Listen when the writing of the file is done
  dest.on('finish', async () => {
    console.log('start uploading in gcloud !');
    await firebaseBucket.upload('/tmp/archive.mp4', {
      gzip: true,
      destination: `{pathToFileInBucket}/archive.mp4`,
      metadata: {
        cacheControl: 'no-cache',
      },
    });
    console.log('uploading finished');
  });
});
```

firebaseBucket is my gcloud bucket already configured elsewhere, define your own bucket using `@google-cloud/storage`

As my function where triggered by link, don't forget to put a response and catch errors to avoid timed out cloud functions (running for nothing, billed for nothing :D)